# Link two foreach loops

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach

I'm struggling with a situation where I got two `foreach` loops.

Here's an example:

```
foreach($hostname in $csv) 
{
     foreach($dom in $domain)
     {
           $x = ($import -split '=')[1].substring(0)
           & $exe $arg1':'$hostname'.m'$dom'.local'
     }
}
```

The script should execute my application like this (just an example):

```
EXAMPLE.exe /h:examplehostname1.mEXAMPLEDOMAIN.local
```

So every hostname got only one domain. When I execute the script like this, it writes out several different hostnames (how it should be), but every hostname got the same domain (how it shouldn't be). So how can I 'link' those two `foreach` loops?

Comment: I would recommend building the argument string differently (like this: `"${arg1}:${hostname}.m${dom}.local"`). Other than that the statement should be run for every combination of hostnames and domains. If it doesn't please provide example input and the output you expect from that input.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two arrays of corresponding hostnames and domains, like so:

```
$csv = @('host1','host2','host3')
$doms = @('domain1','domain2','domain3')
```

use a `for` loop and index into each array:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $csv.Count; $i++){
  $hostname = $csv[$i]
  $domain   = $doms[$i]
  "{0}.{1}.com" -f $hostname,$domain
}
```

Result:

```
host1.domain1.tld
host2.domain2.tld
host3.domain3.tld
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Should've thought "out of the box".